# Pivot Structure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I need a sql query to populate data in a pivotal structure, lets say I have the below table as example, I need a query in SQL server 2008

```
ID|EMAIL|Name|Region|Catergory
1|a@a.com|A|AMERICA|PP 
2|b@b.com|B|EMEA|CC 
3|c@c.com|C|APAC|PP 
4|d@d.com|D|APAC|DD 
5|E@c.com|E|EMEA|CC 
6|E@d.com|ED|UNKNOW|CC
```

Is there any way to get the below pivot structure table,
    Below is the result i would want from the above table in counts,

```
Category|AMERICAS|EMEA|APAC|UNKNOW 

PP|1|0|0|0 
CC|0|2|0 
DD|0|0|1|0
```

Comment: The phrase `Please provide me a query` makes me think you're not approaching this site with the right attitude.

Comment: thams bendataclear, i have removed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT id, Catergory, region
  FROM table1
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(ID)
  FOR Region IN([AMERICAS],
                [EMEA],
                [APAC],
                [UNKNOW])
) AS p;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34eaf/2)

---

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Region)
                      FROM table1
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT id, Catergory, region
  FROM table1
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(ID)
  FOR Region IN(' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

execute(@query);
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34eaf/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
     ID INT, 
     Name CHAR(2), 
     Region VARCHAR(10), 
     Catergory CHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ID, Name, Region, Catergory)
VALUES 
     (1, 'A', 'AMERICA', 'PP'), 
     (2, 'B', 'EMEA', 'CC'), 
     (3, 'C', 'APAC', 'PP'), 
     (4, 'D', 'APAC', 'DD'), 
     (5, 'E', 'EMEA', 'CC'), 
     (6, 'ED', 'UNKNOW', 'CC')

SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT Name, Region, Catergory 
     FROM @temp
) src
PIVOT (
     COUNT(Name) 
     FOR Region IN (AMERICAS, EMEA, APAC, UNKNOW)
) pvt
```

Output -

```
Catergory AMERICAS    EMEA        APAC        UNKNOW
--------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
CC        0           2           0           1
DD        0           0           1           0
PP        0           0           1           0
```